# Need help in understanding this ANR report

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-anr-dialog

I have some custom drawing logic that makes use of a StaticLayout. There is some auto-sizing logic that creates new instances of StaticLayout's in order to find the optimal size of the text to show. Very rarely I see ANR's however and trying to understand what exactly is causing these when they happen. Here is what it says

```
    "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
  | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x738bfc20 self=0x7e282c4a00
  | sysTid=31483 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7e2d5109c8
  | state=R schedstat=( 22803957927 398883091 2986 ) utm=2163 stm=117 core=3 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7fff593000-0x7fff595000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
  #00  pc 00000000003973ec  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+212)
  #01  pc 000000000045dba0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+348)
  #02  pc 00000000004752bc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art14DumpCheckpoint3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+880)
  #03  pc 000000000045e9b0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread21RunCheckpointFunctionEv+416)
  #04  pc 00000000004e20a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art16JniMethodFastEndEjPNS_6ThreadE+92)
  #05  pc 0000000000556360  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_graphics_Paint_nGetFontMetricsInt__JJLandroid_graphics_Paint_00024FontMetricsInt_2+208)
  at android.graphics.Paint.nGetFontMetricsInt (Paint.java)
  at android.graphics.Paint.getFontMetricsInt (Paint.java:2193)
  at android.text.MeasuredText.addStyleRun (MeasuredText.java:199)
  at android.text.StaticLayout.generate (StaticLayout.java:754)
  at android.text.StaticLayout.<init> (StaticLayout.java:534)
  at android.text.StaticLayout.<init> (StaticLayout.java:479)
  at android.text.StaticLayout.<init> (StaticLayout.java:457)
  at android.text.StaticLayout.<init> (StaticLayout.java:437)
```

Comment: This issue resolved for you?
Do you came to root cause of it?(if you recall/remember)

Answer (score 0):

Creating new layouts repetitively is certainly something **expensive** on UI thread, which blocks the thread until the job gets done which doesn't happen because of the new layout creation as soon as the previous one gets done. So it results in blocking UI a few seconds and Android flags your app as non responsive due to the heavy processing you're running on UI (what user feels) and show user an ANR dialog allowing him/her to stop the app and pulls the thread back out of misery.

What you should do is move your job on a background thread an reach the UI with a `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())` if your algorithm works like that or you can try to change your algorithm somehow to get it done without UI blocking and user noticing.

Comment: The weird part is that its not this straightforward. As an experiment I ran this StaticLayout initialization 1000 times inside a while loop and yet I can't repro the crash. Hence trying to understand under what circumstances this ANR is invoked. Thanks for taking the time to respond!

Comment: After about 5 seconds of UI blocking according to [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr) which of course differs from device to device.